Token Metadata creation fails
I have a UI to create Solana Token and upload Metadata to IPFS
Uploading to IPFS works sending the fee for token creation works
but when mint accounts are being created transaction fails and also when i succed in getting all transactions to work
it still doesnt add metadata to the token
Here is my code
"use client";

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { WalletMultiButton } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui';
import { WalletModalProvider } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui';
import {
  ConnectionProvider,
  WalletProvider,
  useWallet,
} from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
import { WalletAdapterNetwork } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-base';
import {
  SolflareWalletAdapter,
  PhantomWalletAdapter,
} from '@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
import { Transaction, Connection, clusterApiUrl, PublicKey, SystemProgram, Keypair, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, sendAndConfirmTransaction } from '@solana/web3.js';
import {
  createInitializeMintInstruction,
  createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction,
  createMintToInstruction,
  TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
} from '@solana/spl-token';
import TokenForm from './TokenForm';

if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  window.Buffer = Buffer;
}

const uploadToIPFS = async (file) => {
  const pinataApiKey = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PINATA_API_KEY;
  const pinataSecretApiKey = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PINATA_SECRET_API_KEY;

  if (!pinataApiKey || !pinataSecretApiKey) {
    throw new Error('Pinata API keys are not configured');
  }

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file);

  try {
    const result = await axios.post(
      'https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS',
      formData,
      {
        maxBodyLength: Infinity,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          pinata_api_key: pinataApiKey,
          pinata_secret_api_key: pinataSecretApiKey,
        },
      }
    );
    return `https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/${result.data.IpfsHash}`;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('IPFS Upload Error:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};

const uploadMetadataToIPFS = async (metadata) => {
  const pinataApiKey = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PINATA_API_KEY;
  const pinataSecretApiKey = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PINATA_SECRET_API_KEY;

  if (!pinataApiKey || !pinataSecretApiKey) {
    throw new Error('Pinata API keys are not configured');
  }

  const formData = new FormData();
  const metadataBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)], { type: 'application/json' });
  formData.append('file', metadataBlob);

  try {
    const result = await axios.post(
      'https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS',
      formData,
      {
        maxBodyLength: Infinity,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          pinata_api_key: pinataApiKey,
          pinata_secret_api_key: pinataSecretApiKey,
        },
      }
    );
    return `https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/${result.data.IpfsHash}`;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Metadata Upload Error:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};

const sendFee = async (connection, wallet) => {
  const feeReceiverAddress = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FEE_RECIPIENT_PUBLIC_KEY;
  if (!feeReceiverAddress) {
    throw new Error('Fee receiver address is not configured');
  }

  const feeReceiver = new PublicKey(feeReceiverAddress);
  const feeAmount = 0.01 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL;

  const { blockhash } = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
  
  const transaction = new Transaction().add(
    SystemProgram.transfer({
      fromPubkey: wallet.publicKey,
      toPubkey: feeReceiver,
      lamports: feeAmount,
    })
  );

  transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
  transaction.feePayer = wallet.publicKey;

  const signature = await wallet.sendTransaction(transaction, connection);
  await connection.confirmTransaction(signature, 'confirmed');
};

const TokenCreator = () => {
  const wallet = useWallet();
  const [connection, setConnection] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (wallet.connected && wallet.publicKey) {
      const network = WalletAdapterNetwork.Devnet;
      const newConnection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl(network), 'confirmed');
      setConnection(newConnection);
    } else {
      setConnection(null);
    }
  }, [wallet.connected, wallet.publicKey]);

  const handleSubmit = async (formData) => {
    formData.isMutable = formData.isMutable ?? true;
    setLoading(true);
    setError(null);

    try {
      if (!wallet.connected || !wallet.publicKey) {
        throw new Error('Please connect your wallet first');
      }

      if (!connection) {
        throw new Error('Network connection not established');
      }

      const balance = await connection.getBalance(wallet.publicKey);
      if (balance < 0.2 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL) {
        throw new Error('Insufficient balance to complete the transaction');
      }

      console.log('Sending fee transaction...');
      await sendFee(connection, wallet);
      console.log('Fee transaction sent and confirmed.');

      let imageUrl = '';
      if (formData.image) {
        console.log('Uploading image to IPFS...');
        imageUrl = await uploadToIPFS(formData.image);
        console.log(`Image uploaded to IPFS: ${imageUrl}`);
      }

      const metadata = {
        name: formData.name,
        symbol: formData.symbol,
        description: formData.description,
        image: imageUrl,
        external_url: formData.website,
        attributes: [
          { trait_type: "Twitter", value: formData.twitter },
          { trait_type: "Telegram", value: formData.telegram },
          { trait_type: "Total Supply", value: formData.totalSupply.toString() },
        ],
        isMutable: formData.isMutable,
      };

      console.log('Uploading metadata to IPFS...');
      const metadataUri = await uploadMetadataToIPFS(metadata);
      console.log(`Metadata uploaded to IPFS: ${metadataUri}`);

      console.log('Creating mint account...');
      const mint = Keypair.generate();
      const lamports = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(82);

      // Step 1: Create Mint Account
      const createMintTransaction = new Transaction().add(
        SystemProgram.createAccount({
          fromPubkey: wallet.publicKey,
          newAccountPubkey: mint.publicKey,
          lamports,
          space: 82,
          programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        }),
        createInitializeMintInstruction(
          mint.publicKey,
          9,
          wallet.publicKey,
          null,
          TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
        )
      );

      createMintTransaction.feePayer = wallet.publicKey;
      createMintTransaction.recentBlockhash = (await connection.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash;
      createMintTransaction.partialSign(mint);

      await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, createMintTransaction, [wallet]);
      console.log('Mint account created:', mint.publicKey.toBase58());

      // Step 2: Create Associated Token Account and Mint Tokens
      console.log('Creating associated token account for the creator...');
      const associatedTokenAddress = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
        [
          wallet.publicKey.toBuffer(),
          TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(),
          mint.publicKey.toBuffer(),
        ],
        ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
      );

      const createTokenAccountTransaction = new Transaction().add(
        createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
          wallet.publicKey,
          associatedTokenAddress[0],
          wallet.publicKey,
          mint.publicKey
        )
      );

      createTokenAccountTransaction.feePayer = wallet.publicKey;
      createTokenAccountTransaction.recentBlockhash = (await connection.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash;

      await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, createTokenAccountTransaction, [wallet]);
      console.log('Associated token account created:', associatedTokenAddress[0].toBase58());

      // Mint Tokens to the Associated Token Account
      console.log('Minting tokens to the associated token account...');
      const mintToTransaction = new Transaction().add(
        createMintToInstruction(
          mint.publicKey,
          associatedTokenAddress[0],
          wallet.publicKey,
          formData.totalSupply * 10 ** 9,
          [],
          TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
        )
      );

      mintToTransaction.feePayer = wallet.publicKey;
      mintToTransaction.recentBlockhash = (await connection.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash;

      await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, mintToTransaction, [wallet]);
      console.log('Tokens minted to the associated token account:', associatedTokenAddress[0].toBase58());

      alert(`Token created successfully!\nMint Address: ${mint.publicKey.toBase58()}`);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      setError(err.message || 'An unexpected error occurred');
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="max-w-2xl mx-auto p-4">
      <WalletMultiButton className="bg-blue-600 text-white rounded-md p-2 mb-4" />
      {error && (
        <div className="bg-red-100 border border-red-400 text-red-700 px-4 py-3 rounded relative mb-4">
          {error}
        </div>
      )}
      {wallet.connected ? (
        <TokenForm
          handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
          loading={loading}
        />
      ) : (
        <p className="text-center text-gray-600">
          Please connect your wallet to create a token
        </p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const TokenCreatorWrapper = () => {
  const network = WalletAdapterNetwork.Devnet;

  const wallets = [
    new SolflareWalletAdapter(),
    new PhantomWalletAdapter(),
  ];

  return (
    <ConnectionProvider endpoint={clusterApiUrl(network)}>
      <WalletProvider wallets={wallets} autoConnect>
        <WalletModalProvider>
          <TokenCreator />
        </WalletModalProvider>
      </WalletProvider>
    </ConnectionProvider>
  );
};

export default TokenCreatorWrapper;

And here is my most recent error
Sending fee transaction...
page.jsx:158 Fee transaction sent and confirmed.
page.jsx:162 Uploading image to IPFS...
page.jsx:164 Image uploaded to IPFS: https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmWG7da9JNb2H9ENv3TdD3X3GZvY6Re8ELiTbsXQqHsTsQ
page.jsx:181 Uploading metadata to IPFS...
page.jsx:183 Metadata uploaded to IPFS: https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/Qmat7JhLSkyav7dam2NEE6mrQaCmi2Fx7AepJjK2DwyZwE
page.jsx:185 Creating mint account...
page.jsx:261 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')

I dont know what i need to do to fix this, i have tried with chatgpt and he cant fix it either
I appreciate any help
